# Pass multiple objects into action mailer/email contents in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Would like to find out how to pass multiple objects into action mailer/email contents in rails. I have no issues passing in @announcement, but not sure how to pass in @post and also @user info.

```
announcement_controllers.rb
  def create
    @post = Post.find_by slug: params[:post_id]
    @announcement = @post.announcements.build(announcement_params)
    @announcement.creator = current_user
    if @announcement.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Your announcement was created.'      
      AnnouncementMailer.announcement_alert(@announcement, @post).deliver
      redirect_to :back
    else
      flash[:notice] = 'Unable to create announcement. Make sure you have enter information.'
      redirect_to :back      
    end
  end

announcement_mailer.rb
class AnnouncementMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  binding.pry
  default to: Proc.new { Signup.where(post_id: @post.id, user_id: current_user.id).pluck(:email) }, 
          from: "#{@post.slug}@fundspace.announcement.com"

  def announcement_alert(announcement, post)
    @announcement = announcement
    @post = post    
    mail(subject: "#{@post.slug}: #{@announcement.title}")
  end

end

binding.pry
    1: class AnnouncementMailer < ActionMailer::Base
 => 2:   binding.pry
    3:   default to: Proc.new { Signup.where(post_id: @post.id, user_id: current_user.id).pluck(:email) }, 
    4:           from: "#{@post.slug}@fundspace.announcement.com"
    5: 
    6:   def announcement_alert(announcement, post)
    7:     @announcement = announcement

[1] pry(AnnouncementMailer)> @post
=> nil
[2] pry(AnnouncementMailer)> @announcement
=> nil
[3] pry(AnnouncementMailer)> @user
=> nil
```

binding.pry to check on @post in announcement_mailer.rb returns nil. Not sure why. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic case of your debug code giving you the wrong impression.  Your `@post` is getting passed in fine - but it's happening *after* the call to `binding.pry`.

You pass in your `post` to `announcement_alert`, which sets it as an instance variable. If you updated that method to look like this, you should see it set fine:

```
def announcement_alert(announcement, post)
  @announcement = announcement
  @post = post
  binding.pry    
  mail(subject: "#{@post.slug}: #{@announcement.title}")
end
```

(You're not checking that `post` is an object in your mailer, so it's possible for other code to pass `nil`. That shouldn't be a problem in this case, though - `Post.find_by` will return `nil` if there are no matches, but your `@post.announcements.build` would fail if it had.)

---

This confusion over where `@post` gets set is going to cause problems in your `default` line, too. Statements outside of a method - like your `binding.pry` and your `default to:` - get run when the class is *evaluated*. Statements inside a method - those inside `def announcement_alert` - don't run until that method is called. And, as we saw above, `@post` isn't defined until you call `announcement_method`.

Here's your current `default` statement:

```
default to: Proc.new { Signup.where(post_id: @post.id, user_id: current_user.id).pluck(:email) }, 
        from: "#{@post.slug}@fundspace.announcement.com"
```

Your `to:` parameter is set to a `Proc`, which is great - even though it references `@post`, because it's a `Proc` it doesn't run until it's needed. You'll have set `@post` at that point.

Your `from:` parameter, on the other hand, is just a string. It's outside of a proc. As a result, it tries to evaluate `@post.slug` immediately - and there's no `@post` set yet, leading to an error. Changing it to this fixes it:

```
default to: Proc.new { Signup.where(post_id: @post.id, user_id: current_user.id).pluck(:email) }, 
        from: Proc.new { "#{@post.slug}@fundspace.announcement.com" }
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the comment. Tried your solution. But binding.pry stopping the processing. Additionally, this is the following error I keep getting, "undefined method `slug' for nil:NilClass" in the line "from: "#{@post.slug}@fundspace.announcement.com"". "Post.find_by" works just fine, the announcement can build with no issues. Just can pass the instance variable over to the mailer. Been at this for hours...

Comment: You might like to use [pry-remote](https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry-remote) if you're running your app in some way that makes it hard to get at your pry console. The reason that you're getting that `nil` in your from line is because you haven't wrapped that in a `Proc` too; I'll update my answer with details.

Comment: Thank buddy! took me a while and I had to make some changes. i.e. Proc.new { Signup.where(post_id: @post.id).pluck(:email) }. Then the whole thing worked like a charm. Need to do some more reading on Proc.